# Run an alternate function if ping takes too long to respond

Tags: batch-file, cmd, timeout, ping

I have a batch file that checks whether a ping was successful or not in order to determine whether or not it should execute a specific function, however, once ping is not successful, there is usually always a huge wait time before it determines that it took too long to respond. How can I create another function that would activate, say, once the ping took more than 3 seconds to respond?

Comment: Type `ping /?`.

Comment: @Noodles Ah, didn't find the direct response, but I did find an alternative that effectively improves my code still. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do this:

```
(
 Ping -n 1 %IP_Address% -w 3000 >nul
) || (
 REM Your Code Here
)
```

This will Ping a target one time, with a timeout of 3 seconds, if the Ping command does not receive a response within 3 seconds it executes your code.